# Regex to replace XML comment with a C# Attribute

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, xsd

I have an XML Schema that I'm trying to create C# classes with.  At the moment, I'm working with [XSD2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) to create the classes.  The [original schemas](http://www.spiraltechinc.com/Tmats/) have elements that look something like this:

```
<xs:element name="NumberOfTags" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>ALT\N</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

XSD2Code produces code that looks something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// ALT\N
/// </summary>
public string NumberOfTags { get; set; }
```

The XML comment refers to a TMATS CODE that maps to a [different data representation](http://www.irig106.org/docs/106-11/chapter9.pdf).  I need to capture these codes in some sort of runtime-readable representation so that I can perform this mapping programmatically.  My best idea to achieve this so far is to translate these XML comments to [C# Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and write additional code to reflect over them.

---

So here is my question.  I would like to do a regex-style replace on the code generated by XSD2Code, using Visual Studio Find and Replace, so that the resulting code looks like this:

```
[TmatsCode(@"ALT\N")]
public string NumberOfTags { get; set; }
```

What is the regex that would achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using Visual Studio Find and Replace

Using Visual Studio's Find & Replace, you can use this expression:

```
^.*\<summary\>\n{:b*}///:b*{.*}\n.*\<\/summary\>$
```

And this replacement:

```
\1[TmatsCode(@"\2")]
```

To break it down:

- `^.*\<summary\>\n` - Match on the beginning of a line, any amount of characters uptil  followed by a new line.
- `{:b*}///` capture any whitespace up til the the /// characters. We'll later use this captured whitespace so we can indent the attribute correctly.
- `:b*{.*}` match any whitespace, then capture the remainder as the content we want.
- `\n.*\<\/summary\>$` match on the new line, then till the end of the line of the closing summary element.

For the replacement, `\1` is the whitespace we captured so the attribute is indented to the same place, and `\2` is the summary content.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  One of these days, I'm going to learn regex.  It's on my todo list with about a thousand other things to learn. :/

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=/// \<summary\>\r\n/// )[^\r\n]+(?=\r\n/// \<\/summary\>)
```

will match

```
ALT\N
```

in your example.

EDIT:

VS find and replace? Didn't notice that... the above is .net Regex.

However, continuing in this direction and in answer to your comment... By rewriting the Regex a little to match the entire comment and capturing the inner value in a group, the MatchEvaluator overload of Regex.Replace comes into its own here:

```
Regex.Replace(
 str,
 @"/// \<summary\>\r\n/// (?<tag>[^\r\n]+)\r\n/// \<\/summary\>",
 m => string.Format(
       "[TmatsCode(@\"{0}\"]",
       m.Groups["tag"].Value));
```